# How keep child object rotation, after remove from parent object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created four objects, and added to the pivot1 object, like mrdoob example in this issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1830#issuecomment-5392158, to rotate the four objects around the x-axis pivot1. But after rotate, the individual positions of the four objects are not updated. if I remove the four objects pivot1 they return to starting position.

I need to rotate the four objects in the x-axis and thereafter be able to rotate on the Y axis and Z axis.

How do I do that?

**EDIT**

Here the code in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tKQP6

This is the portion of code that I try to remove from a pivot to use with another.

```
function clear(pivot) {
    moveEnabled = true;
    for (var i in movedCubes) {
        pivot.remove(movedCubes[i]);
        scene.add(movedCubes[i]);
    }
    movedCubes = [];
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code, so it is clear what you have done, and want to do. Preferably a live (jsfiddle.net) example.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, I just did what you suggested!

Comment: Look at the utility function `THREE.SceneUtils.attach( child, scene, parent )` and `THREE.SceneUtils.detach( child, parent, scene )`. Read the source so you understand what they are doing. Notice the args are in a different order.